# PowerServer cannot be accessed after installation

Tags: powerbuilder

I've been tasked to use a new version of powerbuilder and test it's functionalities . One of it's components were powerserver that will enable all PB application to be deployed on either web and mobile.

I have installed all neccessary powerserver items on my local IIS but when i access the url http://localhost/AEM it throws an internal server error:

Handler "PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule" in its module list

This AEM has it's own Application App Pool called AppeonAppPool. The solution i made to access the AEM is to changed the managed pipeline mode from classic to integrated. With implementing that, i can access AEM but when im trying to deploy the PB app using the PowerServer Toolkit, the IDE throws an error: Failed to connect to powerserver "Local PowerServer"

Upon installation, i have not changed anything rather used the default values.

can anyone help me or point where and what i missed?

thanks!

Im using Appeon Powerbuilder 2017 R3 universal

Comment: You should post this on the Appeon Community board as it is actively monitored by Appeon support.

Comment: hmmm they've given me a pdf file to be read. I've posted here to have another opinion regarding the isapi module and it's conflict with appeon powerserver